# Update issue with sqliteManager

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, sqlite

I'm not able to do an update, but inserts and selects work fine.

Note:

1) I'm using the wrapper from: https://github.com/misato/SQLiteManager4iOS

2) The same code works for the INSERT statement, but not for the update

```
//NSString* sqlStr = (@"INSERT INTO sbu (sbuName) VALUES ( 'rrrr' );)"); //WORKS
```

3) Here is the code:

The code associated with this update as follows:

my inline code

```
    NSString* sqlStr = (@"UPDATE User SET Name = 'wweerr' WHERE Id = 19"); //using a direct sql to verify if it works - does not
    SQLiteManager* dbManager =[[SQLiteManager alloc]initWithDatabaseNamed:@"data.db"];
    NSError* error = [dbManager doQuery:sqlStr];
```

from the library:

```
- (NSError *)doQuery:(NSString *)sql {

    NSError *openError = nil;
    NSError *errorQuery = nil;

    //Check if database is open and ready.
    if (db == nil) {
        openError = [self openDatabase];
    }

    if (openError == nil) {     
        sqlite3_stmt *statement;    
        const char *query = [sql UTF8String];
        sqlite3_prepare_v2(db, query, -1, &statement, NULL);

        if (sqlite3_step(statement) == SQLITE_ERROR) {
            const char *errorMsg = sqlite3_errmsg(db);
            errorQuery = [self createDBErrorWithDescription:[NSString stringWithCString:errorMsg encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]
                                                    andCode:kDBErrorQuery];
        }
        //NSLog(@"sql error: %@", error)
        NSInteger result =  sqlite3_finalize(statement);
        errorQuery = [self closeDatabase];
    }
    else {
        errorQuery = openError;
    }
```

Comment: What is the error on the update and what does select ... where Id = 18 give?

Comment: Hi Mark, the strange thing here is that NO error is generated :(
I also made some step-debugging, the flow is not halted at any point..

I'm clueless as to why this is not working..

Comment: what does `select * from User where Id = 19` give

Comment: Hi Mark, I found the pitfall, see my answer below. Also, if you have an answer to this new question I asked here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11547500/why-update-statement-works-with-initwithformat-and-not-with-stringwithformat

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out the pitfall.
I have wrapped the string using the method: **initWithFormat**.

I just assign a variable like this:

```
NSString *sqlStr = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"UPDATE User SET Name = 'some name' WHERE sbuId = 19"];
```

And now I just pass that variable in:

```
NSError* error = [[Utilities dbManager] doQuery:sqlStr];
```

TODO/TO_ASK:

Why this same thing does NOT work with:

```
 NSString* sqlStr = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"UPDATE User SET Name = 'some name' WHERE sbuId = 19"];
```

Answer (score 0):

I would try with "WHERE Id = '19'" (19 with single quotes) because the field may have been defined as text since sqlite fields are weakly typed.

Comment: Hi Shine, I don't think this is the case since when I run this exact query on sqlite manager, it works fine. 

I have also tried what you said just to make sure, but still does not work..